# applescript find default application for a file type

Tags: applescript, webdav

This is my first time using applescript, I'm trying to open a file from a website in the default application for that file type and am not sure how to do it.

For example:

The file http://test.com/1234.docx should open in OpenOffice if they have that installed.

I can only get it to open in Safari, which I don't want because we use WebDav so the file is editable.

Is there any way to find the default text editor and open a url with that program?

Comment: Try `tell application OpenOffice to open yourfile`

Comment: How do you tell if OpenOffice is installed though. And it's the default application for that file type?

Comment: I was assuming you had OpenOffice installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Finder's open command to open a file in the default application:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Abstract.jpg"
end tell
```

`default application of (info for)` gets the default application:

```
tell application "Finder"
    default application of (info for POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Abstract.jpg")
end tell
```

You can use perl to get the default application for a URL scheme:

`VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=1 perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "mailto")[1]'`

Comment: Thanks! I can get the default application now.  One more question though, how would I run that default app in applescript?

Comment: Just use the open command: `tell application "Finder" open default application of (info for POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Abstract.jpg")`

Comment: Is there a way to list all default applications associated with a file?